# How do you schedule jobs across a server cluster?

Tags: cron, scheduled-task

We have jobs that run on single servers on various schedules, but we need to run them on a cluster of servers regardless of which server is going to run them. It is as if we need a cluster-aware CRON (or Windows Scheduler for our Windows servers).

Does anyone have any experience in this? How would you handle such scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [mcollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/). Their [introductory screencast](http://blip.tv/the-marionette-collective/introduction-3827581) is actually quite good.

Answer (score 1):

On windows clusters I am used to schedule on both nodes. At the starting of the batch I check for shared volume existance. If current node own the volume, the batch goes on, otherwise it exit without do anythig.

IF NOT EXIST I:\NUL GOTO NOVOLUMEI

CD I:\

:NOVOLUMEI

Answer (score 0):

How about a cluster resource manager ? (open-source ones are [Torque](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/torque.php), [Oracle Grid Engine](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/tools/oracle-grid-engine-075549.html), or [Slurm](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/))

Comment: A cluster resource manager seems like a massive overkill for something as simple as running a task on any of the available machine. Aren't cluster resource managers for running code on clusters?

Comment: Well, you didn't say how large your cluster is nor how many jobs you have. And what Torque does is essentially to keep track of free machines and dispatch shell scripts to them, according to rules you can optionally define.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [OCS Inventory NG](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/fr/)?